# JSON object being overridden in a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to copy my resume into another object, and change it to greek (to see how the layout of my html will look). My problem is that when I pass my resume through the function, it somehow gets changed to greek outside of the function. Any help would be appreciated. I have changed my information on me resume, but the format is the same. We are not allowed to use any other JS library. The function is greekingResume(). Here is the code:

```
<script>
    let resume = {
        "personalInfo": {
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "lastName": Ross",
            "contactInfo": {
                "address": {
                    "city": "Somewhere",
                    "state": "USA"
                },
                "phoneNumber": "454-555-5555",
                "email": "somedude@gsomeemail.com"
            }
        },
        "education": {
            "degree": "Bachelors of Computer Science",
            "gradDate": "May 2018",
            "schoolInfo": {
                "school": "Some University",
                "city": "Somewhere",
                "state": "USA",
                "relatedCourses": {
                    "programming": [
                        "Fundamentals of Programming",
                        "Object Oriented Programming",
                        "Operating Systems Theory",
                        "C++ Software Development",
                        "Patterns of Software Development"
                    ],
                    "computerScience": [
                        "Discrete Structures",
                        "Introduction to Algorithms and Data Structures",
                        "Computer Networks",
                        "Computer Organization and Architecture",
                        "Introduction to Algorithms",
                        "Database Theory",
                        "Introduction to Computation Theory"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "skills": [{
            "title": "programming",
            "skillSet": [
                "Proficient with C++, C#, C. Familiar with Java, angularJS and HTML/CSS",
                "Designed User Interface changes and applications using Java for a company's product, helped create software that uses an angularJS application to communicate and display data from a Jasper REST server",
                "Designed a Virtual Machine that can use multithreading without the threading library, a Stack, a Graph, a Word  Counting program, and more that all fit to professors specifications"
            ]
        }, {
            "title": "management",
            "skillSet": [
                "Supervise a team of nine employees: oversee daily tasks, shift assignments and area coverage",
                "Coordinate between team members to increase productivity, identifying key strengths and abilities to match job tasks",
                "Utilize time effectively to maintain a standard of duties, resulting in promotion to lead custodian over two buildings"
            ]
        }, {
            "title": "communication",
            "skillSet": [
                "Communicated between team members and manager to ensure project was on track",
                "Provide feedback between managers and employees to ensure a standards of cleaning, employee performance, and other general information or instructions",
                "Increased employee productivity by effectively relaying instructions, resulting in extra time to focus on ancillary work"
            ]
        }, {
            "title": "organization & training",
            "skillSet": [
                "Complete tasks in a timely manner and resolve unexpected issues quickly",
                "Trained others on how to effectively complete tasks to streamline workflow",
                "Quickly learns a new skill and adapt easily to change and improvement"
            ]
        }],
        "experience": [{
            "title": "Software Developer",
            "company": "Cool Current Company",
            "workStartDate": "April 2016",
            "workEndDate": "Present",
            "location": {
                "city": "Somewhere Else",
                "state": "USA"
            }
        }, {
            "title": "Software Developer",
            "company": "SuperDuper Co",
            "workStartDate": "March 2015",
            "workEndDate": "December 2015",
            "location": {
                "city": "Nowhere",
                "state": "USA"
            }
        }, {
            "title": "Sandwich Artist",
            "company": "Sandwich shop",
            "workStartDate": "January 2015",
            "workEndDate": "March 2015",
            "location": {
                "city": "Somewhere",
                "state": "USA"
            }
        }, {
            "title": "Lead Custodian",
            "company": "Some University",
            "workStartDate": "August 2011",
            "workEndDate": "January 2015",
            "location": {
                "city": "Somewhere",
                "state": "USA"
            }
        }]
    };
    let greekWords = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at ex eu turpis lacinia dapibus. Mauris sed porttitor odio, id efficitur nisi. Proin vitae velit iaculis, posuere ante vel, venenatis sem. Integer lorem nulla, tempor id nibh eget, faucibus finibus ante. Pellentesque tempus dictum sapien, quis vulputate enim pharetra sit amet. Nullam nibh lorem, aliquet et ullamcorper in, commodo eget nibh. Suspendisse condimentum massa vel ex varius, a finibus risus rutrum. Vivamus interdum vulputate est, sit amet viverra nisi mattis vitae. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi vel posuere elit, et sagittis ex. Phasellus dictum eu urna tristique porta. Suspendisse efficitur, diam sed porttitor auctor, augue ipsum cursus mi, nec congue neque elit in nisl. Ut a ipsum bibendum, auctor lectus et, feugiat augue. Suspendisse sit amet nulla dapibus, euismod nunc sed, pretium libero. Aenean maximus elit sed lacus accumsan, et ullamcorper ante hendrerit. Aliquam accumsan nunc nulla, non ornare leo semper sed. Etiam tristique scelerisque tincidunt. Nullam venenatis congue mollis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer neque diam, pulvinar eget accumsan in, hendrerit vel dolor. Suspendisse maximus fringilla ultricies. Donec ac maximus augue. Etiam neque ligula, aliquam eu ligula vel, malesuada sodales lorem. Aenean orci augue, pulvinar sed sodales nec, maximus sit amet ex. Mauris rutrum augue eu magna finibus facilisis. Duis vel ligula enim. Nam non augue orci. Nullam facilisis, nibh eget lacinia dapibus, sem nisl tempus nisi, non consectetur ligula mauris et felis. Suspendisse potenti. Integer convallis ullamcorper molestie. Maecenas sit amet tincidunt velit, nec accumsan erat. Nam at scelerisque augue. Phasellus porta lectus vitae nisi aliquam, quis laoreet tellus tristique. Duis vehicula odio a velit commodo tempus. Duis condimentum, lectus sed tempor imperdiet, velit sem vulputate arcu, et pretium enim ante vitae lorem. Aenean ut hendrerit augue. Fusce ultricies posuere nisi. Pellentesque nec turpis nisi. Nulla sodales feugiat arcu eget ultrices. Cras sem velit, maximus ut neque in, scelerisque cursus mauris. Pellentesque mauris lectus, congue non erat vel, dictum commodo diam. Cras sed augue nec ipsum convallis dignissim at et risus. Fusce condimentum placerat porttitor. Vestibulum ante ante, tincidunt at tristique eget, suscipit quis ipsum. Vivamus iaculis euismod libero id laoreet. Quisque leo felis, placerat sit amet placerat at, sodales in quam. Nunc vulputate, sapien id commodo fringilla, ex ante laoreet nunc, in mattis diam magna ut sapien. Pellentesque scelerisque tortor justo, ut venenatis nibh malesuada nec. Donec non commodo magna, sed posuere magna. Morbi imperdiet nisl non luctus rhoncus. Phasellus id mi sed tellus dignissim efficitur accumsan quis ex. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce sed scelerisque tellus, a aliquam leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras sed dolor at augue vehicula rhoncus. Sed ultrices, quam eget faucibus placerat, nulla dui imperdiet urna, vel suscipit dui ex vitae quam. Maecenas magna ligula, vulputate sed purus nec, laoreet tempor massa. Ut eu purus vulputate, faucibus tellus sed, accumsan massa. Sed vestibulum eleifend risus, sed tempus sem varius at. Praesent viverra vel urna vel luctus. Morbi dui ipsum, semper vitae congue quis, vulputate id quam. Donec quis gravida purus.";

    function greekingResume(data, greekWords) {
        let greekObj = {
            arr: greekWords.split(/[^A-Za-z]+/),
            index: 0
        };
        function greekHelper(obj, greekObj) {
            for (let property in obj) {
                if (typeof(obj[property]) === "object") {
                    obj[property] = greekHelper(obj[property], greekObj);
                } else {
                    obj[property] = obj[property].replace(/[A-Za-z]+/g, (function() {
                        return function(matching) {
                            let greekWord = greekObj.arr[greekObj.index++ % greekObj.arr.length];
                            if (matching[0].match(/[A-Z]/)) {
                                if (matching[1] && matching[1].match(/[A-Z]/)) {
                                    greekWord = greekWord.toUpperCase();
                                } else {
                                    greekWord = greekWord[0].toUpperCase() + greekWord.slice(1);
                                }
                            }
                            return greekWord;
                        };
                    }()));
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        return greekHelper(data, greekObj);
    }
    let greekedResume = greekingResume(resume, greekWords);
```

Thank you for the time to look at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

ok now that i tested your script, the reason why `resume` was changed as well is because in javascript passing a variable to a function is already "Assigning" a new value to the parameters passed, just like if you used the equal (=) sign. What happen was like:

`resume = obj //obj inside your greekHelper function`

it was on these lines your `resume` was mutated:

`obj[property] = greekHelper(obj[property], greekObj);`

and

`obj[property] = obj[property].replace(/[A-Za-z]+/g, (function() {`

So for you to avoid that, change this part of your code to add a `newObj` and assign the mutated value to the new object and return that newObj:

```
        var newObj = {};
        for (let property in obj) {

            if (typeof(obj[property]) === "object") {
                newObj[property] = greekHelper(obj[property], greekObj);
            } else {
                newObj[property] = obj[property].replace(/[A-Za-z]+/g, (function() {
```

Here is a working fiddle for you
http://jsbin.com/rotuhap/edit?js,console,output

Here is a good read for you: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

**IGNORE:**
<del>You can change `let resume` to `var resume`, the `resume` was updated as well because you used `let`, `let` binds fresh value rather than keeping an old reference values.</del>

<del>Here is a good read on `let` and `var`:</del>

<del>[“let” keyword vs “var” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword)</del>

<del>For more information about using `let` check this documentation of [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)</del>

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you so much! My other problem was have my window.onload too far down.

Comment: when I check my resume after I greek it, the original resume is still greeked....Not sure why

Comment: How do you check the original resume?

Comment: @Azotherian please improve your code not create functions inside the loop, and also check the compatibility of using `let` instead of `var`

Comment: Ok. I will try the updated answer soon and let you know how it worked out

Comment: @Azotherian If this solves your question please accept as answer, thanks.